# Saving an input on X-editable breaks the flow of edit/save/cancel

Tags: jquery, x-editable

I'm using X-editable, the plain jQuery version, and have added some custom jQuery to add an "Edit" button that should disappear when in editing mode and re-appear after saved or canceled. Everything seems to work except for when text is changed in editing mode and "OK" is clicked. It hides everything and breaks the flow. Any help would be appreciated.

http://codepen.io/admrbsn/pen/EPrajO

My JS:

```
    $(function(){
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

    $('#editable').editable({
    });
    $('#editable').off('click');

    $('.edit-button').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('#editable').editable('toggle'); 
        $('.edit-button').hide();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.editable-cancel, .editable-submit', function(){
        $('.edit-button').show();
    })  
});
```